# iOS 5.x - detecting when user clicked on the search text field

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, searchbar

How do I detect when the user pressed the empty text field in a generic search bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You should set delegate property of your text field (`UITextField` or `UISearchBar`).

2) The you should implement in delegate following method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

or

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

that will be called whenever user wants to enter text.